# DLATK: Resolving (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: mysql

I am currently using the [Differential Language Analysis ToolKit](https://dlatk.wwbp.org/tutorials/tut_dla.html) (DLATK) that relies partly on SQL.

I tried accessing a SQL file *dla_tutorial* in the DLATK file using this code in my terminal (MacOS):

```
dlatkInterface.py -d dla_tutorial -t msgs_zz -c user_id --add_ngrams -n 1 2 3 --combine_feat_tables 1to3gram
```

However, I get this error:

```
*MYSQL Connect ERROR on db:dla_tutorial
(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

I have seen other answers that recommend changing my password for SQL. However, I had some troubles understanding and executing them, and I'm not sure if this is a DLATK-specific problem. If anyone could offer any leads, that would be super helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project is written around a [passwordless user](https://github.com/dlatk/dlatk/blob/11753eb4358ec387bd0d8d1a0cb1aba49efd4201/dlatk/mysqlmethods/mysqlMethods.py#L66) (and [MyISAM](https://github.com/dlatk/dlatk/blob/f3199f483802c94ac8cc943f7b2ff6aead3d848a/dlatk/dlaConstants.py#L55) as a default engine) indicating databases's aren't the projects strong suite.

The username is fixed as the [current logged in user](https://github.com/dlatk/dlatk/blob/f3199f483802c94ac8cc943f7b2ff6aead3d848a/dlatk/dlaConstants.py#L24) [getpass.user](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)

So recommends:

create a non-root user the same as your unix user (replace XXX below with your local user name).

```
create user XXX identified by '';
grant all on DATABASE.* to XXX@localhost;
```

DATABASE is the name of the database where the samples where loaded which is probably `dla_tutorial`by your command line.